# Teradata fastload column length overflow

Tags: teradata

*Error on piom GET ROW: 60, Text: Column length error, row
not returned !ERROR! Delimited Data Parsing error: Column
length overflow(s) in row 2 for column 1*

Sample CSV file that I am attempting to load, along with the fld script is listed below.

```
"zip1","zip2"
"00601","00631"
"00601","00641"
"00601","00624"
"00601","00731"
"00601","00656"
"00601","00669"
"00601","00664"
"00601","00698"
"00601","00606"
```

```
.sessions 2;
ERRLIMIT 40;
.logmech ldap;
.LOGON dummyip.com / dummyuser,pass;
DATABASE DUMMY_DB;
.set record vartext ",";

DROP TABLE ZIP_DISTANCE;
DROP TABLE ZIP_DISTANCE_ERROR1;
DROP TABLE ZIP_DISTANCE_ERROR2;

CREATE SET TABLE ZIP_DISTANCE
(

zip1 VARCHAR(5),
zip2 VARCHAR(5)
)
PRIMARY INDEX ZIP_DISTANCE(zip1, zip2);

RECORD 2;

DEFINE

zip1 (varchar(5)),
zip2 (varchar(5))

FILE="C:\Users\dummyuser\Downloads\gaz2016zcta5distancemiles.csv";

BEGIN LOADING

ZIP_DISTANCE
errorfiles
ZIP_DISTANCE_ERROR1,
ZIP_DISTANCE_ERROR2

CHECKPOINT 5;

INSERT INTO ZIP_DISTANCE
(
ZIP1,
ZIP2
)
VALUES
(
:zip1,
:zip2
);

END LOADING;

.LOGOFF;
```

Comment: Been a while, but try adding `QUOTE YES '"'` after your specifying your delimiter.  That's QUOTE YES single quote double quote single quote.

Comment: Thank you. I realized that later and removed quote and got it resolved. Is it okay to ask another side question? Hope I am not violating policy. I need to insert decimal(16,13) from source and defined as such but it threw an error stating defintion syntax error. Under create statement I tried float because I only really care about first 2 decimal. Even if I do same data type on both places still returns the same error.

Comment: Ask a new question

Comment: Will do. Thanks for your help with quote argument.